# how to use node.js for develop a listener to receive many vehicle tracking data (over tcp)?

Tags: c++, node.js, tcp, listener

we work on a AVL (automatic vehicle location) project.
we will have about 300000 vehicle that send their activity info with GSM (Simcard) modem over TCP protocol.

we have a listener developed by C++ that listens to a specific port.
at the moment, we have about 20000 GPS Devices that communicate data with C++ listener on one specific port.

some times many devices wait until port be free. we should have a scalable listener.

is any better solution for this case. i saw some usages of Node.js for same case.

**my questions :**

**1:what is your idea?is Node.js good approach?**

**2:how design and implement a listener with node.js?**

**3:any other solution?**

Comment: SO is about specific programming Q&A and not about design and architecture. As-is this is too broad for SO format.

Comment: _"...what is your idea?..."_ (a) you ask for better without defined what better is;  (b) you don't say why the existing solution is not working for you; (c) SO is not a design/coding service.

Comment: Dear Ron and Richard, thank you for your comments. i will edit my question's detail now

Answer (score 2):

I would look on some actor model framework, this will allow your application to scale much better, and have higher throughput (but maybe lower latency), if you have a listener at specific endpoint, this is also a potentially a SPOF (Single point of failure) and also single point of bottleneck(Potentially). The solution depends on the requirements for HA, HR, Scaling and performance and other metric's.

I have now idea regarding actor toolkit for node, here is a github page:
https://github.com/benlau/nactor